# How to set up user input asking for a list one at a time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]

I am trying to replicate this python code but I am unsure how to go about asking for a user inputted list one at a time and then how to present the list in order and then randomly. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it

```
total = 0
while True:
    List = input('Enter an item or "done" to stop entering items: ')
    if List == 'done':
        break
print(List)
```

This was my original idea but I don't think it makes any sense

Comment: This code only saves the most recent entered item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append the input on an array:

```
all_values = []
while True:
    value = input('Enter an item or "done" to stop entering items: ')
    if value == 'done':
        break
    all_values.append(value)
print(all_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

items = []
while True:
    x = input('Enter an item or "done" to stop entering items: ')
    if x == 'done':
        break
    items.append(x)

original = ' '.join(items)
print(f'Your items in original order: {original}')

random.shuffle(items)
shuffled = ' '.join(items)
print(f'Your items in random order: {shuffled}')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).